# localstorage in document.ready fails loading on some devices

Tags: javascript, local-storage, web-storage

In my webapp (embedded in an android webview) I have a **login** page:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   if (db.isset("rememberMe") && db.get("rememberMe") == '1' && db.isset("passwordHash") && db.isset("email")) {      
       login(db.get("email"), db.get("passwordHash"));
   }
});

//verify that there are some authentication info in the localstorage
function authenticateUser() {
    if (!db.isset("userID") || !db.isset("token"))  {
        window.location.href ='login.html';
        return false;
        } else return true;
    }
```

The db object is just a localstorage functions wrapper. 
In the page there is a simple login form, with 3 input fields: email, password and a "remember me" checkbox.
The login function simply makes an ajax request to the server than calls a callback function which simply sets userID, token and some other info in the local storage, then redirects to the main page:

```
function loginOK(data) {
          hideLoading();
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          if (data.header.responseCode == "000") {
            if ($("#rememberMeButton").is(':checked')) {
              db.set("rememberMe", "1");
              db.set("passwordHash", data.body.passwordHash);
              }
            else db.set("rememberMe", "0");

            db.set("email", data.body.email);
            db.set("userID", data.body.userID);
            db.set("token", data.body.token);

            if(authenticateUser()) window.location.href="lists.html";
```

in the **lists.html** page the fist operation is a control against not logged in accesses:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      if (!authenticateUser()) return; //IMPORTANT!
      getLists(); //get user's lists infos
});
```

Well everything seems easy and smooth, and actually this code works fine on almost all the mobile devices i've tested it with, but it fails on some other devices. On these devices, if the user successfully  logs in, is redirected to the lists.html page, but then, for some reason, he's redirected back to the login (the authenticateUser function returns false). Plus, if he had set the remember me checkbox then an infinite loop is generated!!!

we can make 3 deductions: 
1) if the user is redirected to the lists page it means that the authenticateUser func returns true on the login page, thus the information is stored in the localstorage. 
2) If the authenticationUsers fails in the lists page, it means that such information is not found in the localStorage anymore
3) When redirected back to the login page, if the user had set the remember me options before, then the automatic login is triggered, and, since the server returns success. This means that the three data (rememberMe value, userID and token) are again available in the login page after the redirection.

How is it possible?
I've discovered that some people had problems with dealing with the localstorage within the document.ready handler function, but I haven't found any official explanation wether this is a wrong usage or not. And, to be honest, I don't think it should be wrong.

So, where is the problem?

UPDATE: the db object definition:

```
function memoryManager() {
            //set an item
            this.set=set;
            function set(name, value) {
                if (value == undefined || value === undefined || value === null ) { return false; }
                //if is an object json-encode it!
                if (typeof value === "object") value = JSON.stringify(value);
                localStorage.setItem(name, value);
                return true;
            }

        //get an item
        this.get = get;
        function get(name) {
            if (localStorage.getItem(name) === null) return null;
            value = localStorage.getItem(name);
            //check if it is an json encoded object or a simple value
            try { JSON.parse(value); }
                catch (e) { return value; }
            return JSON.parse(value);
        }
        //is set an item?
        this.isset = isset;
        function isset(name) {
            if (localStorage.getItem(name) === null) return false;
            else return true;
        }

    }
    //create instance:
    var db = new memoryManager();
```

Comment: You could try some simple debugging on your own. `if(window.localStorage)` returns true if localStoreage is supported. Check that first. After that, try dumping the entire content of the localStoreage to a log or something and see what's stored. My 5 cents. However, I guess this is an issue because not all devices support local storeage. Btw, authentification in javascript is not secure at all.

Comment: Hi, I've already made some debugging and the localStorage is supported . Moreover, as you can see, before redirecting to the lists page I perform the same authenticateUSer function, which looks for the information in the localstorage. The ultimate proof is that, if the loop is generated, it means that the automatic login succeed, and then the information are available again in the login page after the 2° redirection (login->lists, lists->login) No, I guess there must be a more tricky problem, maybe related to localstorage performances and implementation, or reading/writing from memory/disk..

Comment: How is `isset` created? Can't see that method in the docs.

Comment: just updated the question with the db object definition

Comment: I realized that on the same devices on which the webview fails, the (same) application works fine when acceding its online version through the standard android browser!